# HTML semantics for displaying form like data

Tags: html, semantic-markup

I have to display elements like:

```
First Name : (Fetched from Database)

Last Name  : (Fetched from Database)

User Name  : (Fetched from Database)

Address    : (Multiple line of Data Fetched from database)
```

My question is according to semantics which HTML elements are to be used here?

`dt` `dd` are block level element. I have to display label and its value inline.

Comment: Totally depends on you

Comment: You can find a tutorial with a similar example over here: http://www.onextrapixel.com/2009/05/13/how-to-use-dl-dt-and-dd-html-tags-to-list-data-vs-table-list-data/

Comment: As asked, the question is opinion-based. If you asked, for example, with due specifics, which is the most accessible approach (`table` is), then the question would be constructive. In contexts like this, “semantics” is just opinions.

Comment: Does each page only contain one set? Or do you want to display the data of several people? If so, in which visual way? And can’t you  use a block level element because you have to nest it in an element that doesn’t allow them, or don’t you want to use them because they are *displayed* as blocks?

Comment: @unor I am currently doing it with span(inline-block). But i want to write it according to semantics so that i will have to write less code

Comment: This seems to be a perfect use case for the `dl`/`dt`/`dd` elements (a list of key/value pairs). *There is no such thing as "block and inline" elements in HTML now*, it was an HTML4 term that has been obsoleted and replaced with the more meaningful categorization of the content types (https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#kinds-of-content). You can style any element with CSS just as you need.

Answer (score 1):

As for me it's totally depends on you. It can be `ol` for example as it is in starter `ASP.NET MVC 4` project or, as you mentioned `dl`-`dt`-`dd` or just `div`s.

Comment: +1 As stated by this answer...it's all up to you. Also, `span`, `label` and many others are semantically correct

Answer (score 1):

Example taken from here: http://www.onextrapixel.com/2009/05/13/how-to-use-dl-dt-and-dd-html-tags-to-list-data-vs-table-list-data/
You can find the result (demo) over here: http://www.onextrapixel.com/examples/dl-tags-vs-table/

Using dl, dt and dd; you could have a code like this:

HTML

```
<dl>          
    <dt>Name: </dt>
    <dd>John Don</dd>

    <dt>Age: </dt>
    <dd>23</dd>

    <dt>Gender: </dt>
    <dd>Male</dd>

    <dt>Day of Birth:</dt>
    <dd>12th May 1986</dd>
</dl>
```

CSS

```
/*DL, DT, DD TAGS LIST DATA*/
dl {
    margin-bottom:50px;
}

dl dt {
    background:#5f9be3;
    color:#fff;
    float:left; 
    font-weight:bold; 
    margin-right:10px; 
    padding:5px;  
    width:100px; 
}

dl dd {
    margin:2px 0; 
    padding:5px 0;
}
```

Using the ordinary table to display this data, you would have:

HTML

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="title">Name: </td>
        <td class="text">John Don</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="title">Age: </td>
        <td class="text">23</td>
    </tr> 
    <tr>
        <td class="title">Gender: </td>
        <td class="text">Male</td>
    </tr>     
    <tr>
        <td class="title">Day of Birth:</td>
        <td class="text">12th May 1986</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

CSS

```
/*TABLE LIST DATA*/
table {
    margin-bottom:50px;
}

table tr .title {
    background:#5f9be3;
    color:#fff;
    font-weight:bold;
    padding:5px; 
    width:100px;   
}

table tr .text {
    padding-left:10px;
}
```

[image: table vs dl, dt and dd]

Comment: if you added thead with th's for columns or changed first td to th, your example would be much more semantic ;)  your picture is cute but it seems like you are focusing on how the data is styled more than which is more semantic

Comment: The example comes from a site I've found. I actually just copy-pasted it. It explains that there's no difference in using them and that using DL, DT and DD tags looks cleaner

Comment: how does it explain that? there's a huge difference in using dl and table in terms of accessibility. huge.

Answer (score 0):

i could argue for both given answers, `<table>`, and `<dl>`, and even argue pro/con about `<ol>`, as well as `<ul>` because thats semantics. either route you chose, you should be empowering your markup with microformats, or microdata, or rdfa, or combos of them. i'm going to focus on microformats because they are very easy to implement, are the most widely used semantic web technology deployed on the web, and i've used them in nearly the exact situation you are in right now.

posh markup + microformats = real world semantics.
or posh markup + microdata = real world semantics.
as well as posh markup + rdfa = real world semantics.

whichever element(s) you chose to markup your content in, give it real semantics, while making it more accessible and portable, by applying html classes (microformats) to them. they also double as easy style/interaction hooks. in your case, i would mark up each user with an hcard, then provide a way for the user to access/view/save the vcard, instead of it just saving to your desktop as most vcard implementations poorly do. check them out:
http://microformats.org